# Integrating around a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have a function $$f(x,y)=1/2x^2y-2x+1/6y^3-5/2 y$$ and I need to find $\int_{d1}\nabla f\cdot dr$ with $d_1$ being orientated from the second quadrant towards the fourth quadrant.

$d_1$ will be the straight edge of D which is $$d_1 = \{(x,y):  x^2 +y^2\le 9 \mathrm{\ and\ } x+y=0\}$$

Ok so D is just the whole circle which means the line will intersect at $3\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ and I know we are going to be integrating from top left to bottom right (quadrant 2 - 4) would this mean we are going counter clockwise around the circle??

Furthermore I did manage to calculate the gradient which came out to be $∇f=<xy-2, 1/2$ $x^2-y^2/2$ $-5/2>$ so how exactly would I go about setting up this integral and solving it with polar coordinates and am I correct in assuming it will be going counter clockwise?

Comment: In your equation about $D$, is it $x+y\ge 0$ or $\le 0$. That will fix the domain.

Comment: $D = \{(x,y):  x^2 +y^2\le 9 \mathrm{\ and\ } x+y>=0\}$ so your first suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says $d_1$ is the straight edge of $D$ which is $x+y = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 9$. That means straight line segment from $A \ (-\frac{3}{\sqrt2}, \frac{3}{\sqrt2})$ to $B \ (\frac{3}{\sqrt2}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt2})$.

So parametrize the line segment as $ \ \vec {r}(t) = (t, -t), -\frac{3}{\sqrt2} \leq t \leq \frac{3}{\sqrt2}$.

Now please note that you are finding line integral of $\vec F$ which is a conservative vector field as $\vec F = \nabla f$.

So your line integral will simply be $f(B) - f(A)$

Comment: Ok that actually makes some sense I got -4 does that sound right? Also what if I was integrating around the top half of the circle? Like when $\int_{d2}\nabla f\cdot dr$ with $d_1$ being orientated from fourth to second instead of second to fourth?

Comment: No I get $\displaystyle - \frac{15}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: how exactly are you getting that?

Comment: $f = \frac{1}{2}x^2y - 2x + \frac{1}{6} y^3 - \frac{5}{2} y$, correct? Now plug in coordinates of point $A$ and $B$ and subtract $f(A)$ from  $f(B)$

Comment: I edited my post I tried that which gives me the same value but positive and I know it should be negative since we are going down.

Comment: You do not need to do any of that. Did you understand my point about it being a conservative vector field which means the line integral only depends on the starting and end points and not on the path?

Comment: Also you are going in the wrong direction. It cannot be $-\pi/4$ to $3 \pi/4$. It should be the other way round. The question says you are going from 2nd quadrant to 4th, not from 4th to 2nd.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but I am getting -5.3 did you include the -5/2 y term because without it I get what you got.

Comment: I just confirmed my calc using WolframAlpha. Type this in WolframAlpha: find 1/2x^2y-2x+1/6y^3-5/2 y where x = 3/\sqrt2, y = -3 / \sqrt2    which is the end point. Then type for point $A$ and subtract  the value from above

Comment: ok I understand now thank you! Do you happen to know how to do it around the circle (see the top comment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121204/discussion-between-math-lover-and-unsure).